# chamar uma pagina passando parametros na url

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um arquivo HTML simples que é acessado por:

`https:111.111.111:8080/index.html/?login="me"&password="1234"`

O problema é que ao tentar acessá-lo dá página inexistente. 
Coloquei uma página `teste.html` lá, com HTML puro e acessei com `https:111.111.111:8080/teste.html` e acessou normal, acredito que possa ser algum problema com os parâmetros. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue abaixo o código da minha página:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

    <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="pass"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function myFunction() {

            var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

            var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
            l = unescape(temp[1]);
            temp = parameters[1].split("=");
            p = unescape(temp[1]);
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = l;
            document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML = p;
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Tente assim: `https:111.111.111:8080/index.html?login=me&password=1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nas aspas da url:

```
https:111.111.111:8080/index.html?login=me&password=1234
```

Acho que resolve.